# SAS format alphanumeric

Tags: sas

when I ran this code in sas to modify the format of a complex alphanumeric column  $CDCLOANTI.  to a simple alphanumeric format compatible with a SAS vas connected to sql server, the result of this variable is always empty after execution

```
data PP;

  set table1;

   CD = input(CD, $CDCLOANTI.);

   format CD $200.; 

   CD = put(CD, $200.);

run;
```

Comment: Did the LOG window show any messages? What is the value of option FMTERR? (`proc options option=FMTERR; run;`)

Answer (score 0):

With the `CD =` statement you are actually changing the value of the `CD` variable.

- `INPUT()` uses **informats**
- `PUT()` uses **formats**

You might need only a switch to `PUT` to capture the formatted value.

```
putlog 'NOTE: CD raw value: ' CD $200.;
putlog 'NOTE: CD current format per data set: ' CD;
putlog 'NOTE: CD mapped through format $CDCLOANTI: ' CD $CDCLOANTI.;

CD = put(CD, $CDCLOANTI.);

putlog 'NOTE: CD raw value after $CDCLOANTI transform: ' CD $200.;
```

Comment: I don't know Richard, if I understood your answer correctly, but my problem is that I can't convert the alphanumeric variable CD with the complex format $CDCLOANTI. also in alphanumeric format $200.